# How to use jaxb2-annotate-plugin with XJC in command line

Tags: xsd, jaxb, xjc, annox, jaxb2-annotate-plugin

I'm building java classes based on an xsd using "jaxb-ri" in command line (xjc.bat).
I want to set a namespace in an XmlType annotation using jaxb2-annotate_plugin but I don't know how to add this plugin to xjc classpath and acitvate it.

here is my external bindings.xjb file :

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
              xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
              jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox"
              version="2.1">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="myschema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='MyType]">
            <annox:annotateClass>@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType(namespace="urn:myschematwo")</annox:annotateClass>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

My command line is :

```
D:/jaxb-ri/bin/xjc.bat -p "com.jaxb.mypackage" -d
"D:/myproject/src/main/java" D:/myschema.xsd -b "D:/bindings.xjb"
-extension
```

When I execute this command, I have an error message saying that "http://annox.dev.java.net" is not supported.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that correct jars are within classpath e.g. 
`xjc.bat -classpath "jaxb2-basics-annotate-0.6.0.jar"`

Comment: Thanks for your response, I did that but I got the following error ==>  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jvnet/jaxb2_commons/plugin/AbstractParameterizablePlugin
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)

Comment: I think that missing also `jaxb2-basics-tools-0.6.0.jar`. Try to add it in the classpath.

Comment: I looked for all missed libraries each time I had a NoClassFound but in final, I had the first error message saying that "http://annox.dev.java.net" is not supported. Here is the added libraries                                                                   -classpath "../lib/jaxb2-basics-annotate-1.0.2.jar";"../lib/tools-0.4.1.5.jar";"../lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar";"../lib/jaxb2-basics-runtime-0.9.5";"../lib/annox-1.0.1.jar";"../lib/javaparser-1.0.11.jar";"../lib/jaxb2-basics-tools-0.9.5.jar"

Comment: You must remove the `"` character between libraries .. Should be `-classpath "../lib/jaxb2-basics-annotate-1.0.2.jar;../lib/tools-0.4.1.5.jar;../lib/comm‌​ons-logging-1.1.1.jar;../lib/jaxb2-basics-runtime-0.9.5;../lib/annox-1.0.1.ja‌​r;../lib/javaparser-1.0.11.jar;../lib/jaxb2-basics-tools-0.9.5.jar"`

Comment: Still have the same error Binding spacename ---> "http://annox.dev.java.net" not supported. Do you maybe mean "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" ?

Comment: Yes .. we're missing an extraargument `-Xannotate` add it at the end of command.

Comment: Unfortunately, Still get the same error

Comment: As last option , i've some doubts about the libraries versions. [See Here](http://static.highsource.org/jaxb2-basics/jaxb2-basics-annotate/dependency-management.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of [jaxb2-annotate-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin).

First, I don't provide sample for command line as (as far as I know) nobody uses command line or batch scripts for schema compilation. At least up to date there were no requests for that. There are [samples](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/tree/master/samples/annotate) for [Ant](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/blob/master/samples/annotate/project-build.xml) and [Maven](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin/blob/master/samples/annotate/project-pom.xml), the one for Ant is the closes to the command line usage.

Next, I wonder what is in `xjc.bat`.

If it calls `xjc.exe` from Java distibution, this most probably won't work with third-party plugins at all, not just with the `jaxb2-annotate-plugin`. The reason is that the XJC version which is distributed with Java has a renamed package: `com.sun.tools.**` -> `com.sun.tools.internal.**`. This breaks, naturally compagtibility with plugins. So please make sure `xjc.bat` does not call the `xjc.exe` contained in the Java distro.

I hope `xjc.bat` calls `com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCFacade` from JAXB RI Jars.

To execute the plugin you'll need two things:

- Include all the required dependencies to the classpath.
- Turn the plugin on using `-Xannotate` command line parameter.

These dependencies are:

```
                <!-- JAXB2 Basics library -->
                <include name="jaxb2-basics-*.jar"/>
                <include name="jaxb2-basics-annotate*.jar"/>
                <!-- JAXB2 Basics library dependencies -->
                <include name="annox-*.jar"/>
                <include name="javaparser-*.jar"/>
                <include name="commons-beanutils-*.jar"/>
                <include name="commons-logging-*.jar"/>
                <include name="commons-lang3-*.jar"/>
```

Here's the full dependency tree (with versions):

```
[INFO] org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-annotate:jar:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-tools:jar:0.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.7:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.7:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.11:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:2.16:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.12:provided
[INFO] |     \- javax.xml.bind:jsr173_api:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.2.7:provided
[INFO] +- org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin-testing:jar:0.9.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:jar:0.9.0:test
[INFO] |     +- org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin-core:jar:0.9.0:test
[INFO] |     |  +- com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal:resolver:jar:20050927:test
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9:test
[INFO] |     |  +- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.7:test
[INFO] |     |  \- org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.9:test
[INFO] |     |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.9:test
[INFO] |     |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.9:test
[INFO] |     |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.9:test
[INFO] |     |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.9:test
[INFO] |     |     |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.9:test
[INFO] |     |     |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-2:test
[INFO] |     |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.9:test
[INFO] |     |     \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:test
[INFO] |     |        \- classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:test
[INFO] |     +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.15:test
[INFO] |     +- org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb22-plugin:jar:0.9.0:test
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.2:test
[INFO] |        \- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0:test
[INFO] +- org.jvnet.annox:annox:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.javaparser:javaparser:jar:1.0.11:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
```

Maven stuff is unrelated, otherwise you should be able to see the versions.

Hope this helps.

To be honest, I am a bit reluctant to invest time in batch/command-line sample. But if you'll get one working, I'd add it to samples.

Why do you actually need it in the command line?

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I never used Jaxb before. A colleague gave me jaxb-ri package, it's why I used it. Is there any tutorial to use the builder in eclipse ? Thank in advance.

Comment: @Samy A Maven project with `maven-jaxb2-plugin` in `pom.xml` works in Eclipse basically OOTB.

Comment: Trying to get this working in Gradle but it's really kicking my buttocks. :-(

Comment: @user447607 Really? Ask a question. I'm not much into Gradle but colleagues use this plugin in Gradle builds.

Comment: @lexicore I finally got it working yesterday. Had to use just the right libraries, etc.  Annox and CXF 3.1.4 wsdl2java generation don't seem to like each other much at all.  Set 3.0.3 in Spring dependency management plugin. Probably should eliminate Annox annotations in favor of newer Java standard annotations anyway.

Comment: @user447607 Yes, I'd recommend to use Java notation. It's still parsed by Annox, so the dependency will stay anyway.