# How to use jaxb2-annotate-plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, jaxb, jaxb2-annotate-plugin

I just learned how to generate Java classes from XSD using JAXB (with Maven), now I need to add to my generated classes some annotations. I found out that `jaxb2-annotate-plugin` does exactly this, but I don't know how to use it in my project.
Can anyone provide some step-by-step tutorials or helpful explanation? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26545603/3364187)

Comment: The plugin has a pretty good documentation: https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jaxb2-annotate-plugin with XJC in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525642/how-to-use-jaxb2-annotate-plugin-with-xjc-in-command-line)